# My headphone is connected but not making sound

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

I use **Windows 10** as primary operating system but recently I found a better way to dual boot Ubuntu. A software named **Wubi** works great for dual booting any linux distro (not sure about all but I tried **Mint, Xubuntu, Ubuntu 20.04**). So, I installed **Ubuntu 20.04** using **Wubi** and it's awesome I was a point when I started using as the primary system. Now, I always work on Ubuntu and for little if I want to play games I start **Windows 10**.

But my happiness using **Ubuntu** didn't lasted long, today when I was trying to listen music using a headphone it was not making sound. So as usual I searched on google about this problem saw many videos also tried many fix shown on many articles but none of them worked for many.

The fixes I tried are:

1. opening alsamixer from terminal and tweaking sound and unmuting.
2. adding

   options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode

   options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi

these lines on alsa-base.conf

and nothing ended up helping me... Please help me I know this is not a permanent problem but also I don't know how to fix this and I just created account on askubuntu.com just for asking this question so if i've done any mistake forgive me please..

Comment: I guess wubi installs are off-topic. Can you boot form an Ubuntu LiveUSB and check if you have the problem there?

Comment: It is hard to dual boot using LiveUSB or Disk ( It's hard for me don't know about others). That is the reason i'm using Wubi for using Ubuntu.

Comment: It is not "hard" to boot from a USB. Using wubi may work, but you can get all kind of problems and almost no way to get support.

Comment: Can you link me to a guide how to boot from USB.

Comment: Insert an Ubuntu LiveUSB to a USB port and select it as a boot device in BIOS. As simple as that.

Comment: How do I make the usb boot Ubuntu.. I mean how to mount Ubuntu OS on the USB?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview